# Hide header Checkbox in DatagridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a requirement where in I need to have checkbox columns in first column of the datagaridview. So when I add the checkbox , it adds the same in the header of teh same column as well. This header checkbox is not required for me. I want to hide it out. I am not able to achieve this. I haev tried the Cell painitng technique but its not working out for me :(.. Pls help

```
                        ckBox = new CheckBox();
                        ckBox.Size = new Size(14, 14);
                        //Get the column header cell bounds
                        Rectangle rect = dgv_CourseList.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0,-1, true);
                        Point oPoint = new Point();
                        oPoint.X = rect.Location.X + 3;
                        oPoint.Y = rect.Location.Y + 2;

//check only for cells of first column and only header
        if (this.dgv_CourseList.Columns[0].Index == e.ColumnIndex && e.RowIndex < 0)
        {

                // You can change e.CellStyle.BackColor to Color.Gray for example
                using (Brush backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor))
                {
                    // Erase the cell.
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            //}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use an empty string for the column header text ?

Comment: I don't understand how having a CheckBoxColumn would crete a CheckBox in the Header. This sounds totally wrong. Show us the code that leads to this instead of trying to painting over it! (Also: Please watch your spelling and formatting!)

Comment: You must show the code, which create the column and fill it. Standard DataGridView column header is just a text.

Comment: Heelo folks, I have added the piece of code which I have used to display the checkbox in the first column of the datagridview

Comment: I found th trick to make it hidden...was ignoring a piece of code:(